# change the bottom anchor constraint to 50 pixels from the bottom

Tags: swift, constraints, init, cgrect

I want the imgView to have a gap of 50 from the bottom. I dont know how to get a gab at the bottm. I have tried to do bottomAnchor - 50 but that does not work it causes a compile error. It says its not allowed because this is a binary statement.What I tried to code is below.

```
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
      imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor-50).isActive = true


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed syntax. Update your code as follow will fix your issue.

```
imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
```

If you are writing this code inside Subclass of `UIView` then add following line of code.

```
imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
```

Set bottom constraint value to `-50` or `50` based on your requirement.